# How can I add multiple properties for a class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add multiple properties to "Person" class. This instance will be called by `getDetails()` method. So I easily can pass an array of values to my objects (variable), ex.   `var john = new Person("John Doe", "32", "Web Developer");`.

```js
function Person(name, age, occupation) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.occupation = occupation;
}
Person.prototype.getDetails = function () {
  return this.name;
  return this.age;
  return this.occupation;
};
var john = new Person("John Doe", "32", "Web Developer");

document
  .getElementById('demo')
  .innerText = john.getDetails();
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Class Method</h2>

<p>How to define and use a Class method.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: The "adding properties" part is correct. Do `console.log(john)` and you will see that too. The way you are inspecting your data is incorrect. Since a function can only `return` *once*, anything after `return this.name;` is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that after **return** all code is unreachable!

So you need to concatenate the properties and combine as a one string like this:

```js
function Person(name, age, occupation) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.occupation = occupation;
}
Person.prototype.getDetails = function () {
  return this.name + " " + this.age + " " + this.occupation;
};
var john = new Person("John Doe", "32", "Web Developer");

document
  .getElementById('demo')
  .innerText = john.getDetails();
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Class Method</h2>

<p>How to define and use a Class method.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```